# Turtle in haskell: How to switch to a directory obtained from inshell command?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I am learning Haskell and I am having a hard time performing the following task.

I have a script that gives me a directory. I would like to call that script, get the directory and then use the "cd" in Turtle to change the directory. Below is the code that I currently wrote but it fail to compile.

It says `lineToText targetDirLine` expects `Line` and not `Maybe Line` . I do not understand why `fold (inshell "getSomeDir" empty) Fold.head` produces `Maybe (Maybe Line)`.

Even after fixing this error I get other issue using `cd`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-10.2 script

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Control.Foldl as Fold                         
import Turtle              

getDirAndCd :: MonadIO io => io ()
getDirAndCd = cd fp
              where (Just targetDirLine) = fold (inshell "getSomeDir" empty) Fold.head
                    fp = fromText (lineToText targetDirLine)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the type of the `fold` expression with GHCi:

```
λ> :t fold (inshell "getSomeDir" empty) Fold.head
fold (inshell "getSomeDir" empty) Fold.head
  :: MonadIO io => io (Maybe Line)
```

you'll see that it's not a `Maybe Line`, it's an `io (Maybe Line)`.  When you write, in your `where` clause:

```
where Just targetDirLine = fold (inshell "getSomeDir" empty) Fold.head
```

it tries to match the `Maybe` on the left with the `io` on the right, and so `io (Maybe Line)` unifies with `Maybe (Maybe Line)`, and that's why you get the type error you do.

You'll want to process the `fold` expression in a `<-` line in the `do`-block:

```
getDirAndCd :: (MonadIO io) => io ()
getDirAndCd = do
  Just targetDirLine <- fold (inshell "getSomeDir" empty) Fold.head
  let fp = fromText (lineToText targetDirLine)
  cd fp
```

This will result in another error, `Could not deduce (MonadFail io)`.  The issue here is that `Just targetDirLine <- ...` represents a pattern that could fail, if `fold` returns a `Nothing`.  If you add a `MonadFail io` constraint, it type checks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Control.Foldl as Fold
import Turtle

getDirAndCd :: (MonadFail io, MonadIO io) => io ()
getDirAndCd = do
  Just targetDirLine <- fold (inshell "getSomeDir" empty) Fold.head
  let fp = fromText (lineToText targetDirLine)
  cd fp
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! Now I understand what I missed.